# Merge is overwriting the values of one column with the values from another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tried writing this a few different ways and still get the same results

I am trying to get a count of units and a count of units that are flagged with yes for campaigns
then get the ratio of units to units with campaigns. But when I perform the merge the values in column camp_count is being overwritten by the values in the column unit_count

This is what I have been using.

```
def campaign_sorter(x, y):
    new_df = x[['VFMFRC', 'VFUNIT', 'IS_MONTH', 'IS_DAYS_GROUP', 'CAMPAIGN_PROFILE']].copy()

    # Counting distinct unit numbers by IS_MONTH, IS_DAYS_GROUP, and other columns
    unit_count = new_df.groupby(['IS_MONTH', 'IS_DAYS_GROUP', 'VFMFRC', 'CAMPAIGN_PROFILE']).agg({'VFUNIT': 'nunique'}).reset_index()
    unit_count.columns = ['IS_MONTH', 'IS_DAYS_GROUP', 'VFMFRC', 'CAMPAIGN_PROFILE', 'UnitCount']

    # Counting distinct comp code values by IS_MONTH, IS_DAYS_GROUP, and other columns
    camp_count = new_df[new_df['CAMPAIGN_PROFILE'] == 'Y'].groupby(['IS_MONTH', 'IS_DAYS_GROUP', 'VFMFRC', 'CAMPAIGN_PROFILE']).agg({'VFUNIT': 'nunique'}).reset_index()
    camp_count.columns = ['IS_MONTH', 'IS_DAYS_GROUP', 'VFMFRC', 'CAMPAIGN_PROFILE', 'CampCount']

    # Merging the unit counts and comp code counts DataFrames
    merged_df = pd.merge(unit_count, camp_count, on=['IS_MONTH', 'IS_DAYS_GROUP', 'VFMFRC', 'CAMPAIGN_PROFILE'], how='left', suffixes=('_unit', '_comp'))

    # Calculating the RPU (Ratio of Unit Count to Comp Code Count)
    # merged_df['RPU'] = merged_df['UnitCount'] / merged_df['CampCount']


    # Merging the RPU values with the original dataframe
    # new_df = pd.merge(new_df, merged_df[['IS_MONTH', 'IS_DAYS_GROUP', 'VFMFRC', 'CAMPAIGN_PROFILE', 'RPU']], on=['IS_MONTH', 'IS_DAYS_GROUP', 'VFMFRC', 'CAMPAIGN_PROFILE'], how='left')

    # Dropping unnecessary columns and removing duplicates
    # new_df = new_df.drop(columns=['IS_MONTH']).drop_duplicates()

    return merged_df
```

The output from unit_count gives me

|  | IS_MONTH | IS_DAYS_GROUP | VFMFRC | CAMPAIGN_PROFILE | UnitCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-07-01 | 030 | CompA | N | 20 |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 030 | CompB | N | 12 |
| 2 | 2021-07-01 | 030 | FTL | N | 50 |
| 3 | 2021-07-01 | 030 | FTL | Y | 7 |
| 4 | 2021-07-01 | 060 | CompA | N | 11 |
| 5 | 2021-07-01 | 060 | CompB | N | 5 |
| 6 | 2021-07-01 | 060 | FTL | N | 28 |
| 7 | 2021-07-01 | 090 | CompA | N | 9 |
| 8 | 2021-07-01 | 090 | CompB | N | 15 |
| 9 | 2021-07-01 | 090 | FTL | N | 33 |
| 10 | 2021-07-01 | 090 | FTL | Y | 4 |

The output from camp_count gives me

|  | IS_MONTH | IS_DAYS_GROUP | VFMFRC | CAMPAIGN_PROFILE | CampCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-07-01 | 030 | FTL | Y | 7 |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 090 | FTL | Y | 4 |
| 2 | 2021-07-01 | 120 | CompB | Y | 3 |
| 3 | 2021-07-01 | 120 | FTL | Y | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-07-01 | 150 | CompB | Y | 2 |
| 5 | 2021-07-01 | 150 | FTL | Y | 1 |
| 6 | 2021-07-01 | 180 | CompB | Y | 1 |
| 7 | 2021-07-01 | 180 | FTL | Y | 15 |
| 8 | 2021-07-01 | 210 | CompA | Y | 1 |
| 9 | 2021-07-01 | 210 | CompB | Y | 5 |
| 10 | 2021-07-01 | 210 | FTL | Y | 25 |

But when the merge happens I end up with

|  | IS_MONTH | IS_DAYS_GROUP | VFMFRC | CAMPAIGN_PROFILE | UnitCount | CampCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-07-01 | 030 | CompA | N | 20 | NaN |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 030 | CompB | N | 12 | NaN |
| 2 | 2021-07-01 | 030 | FTL | N | 50 | NaN |
| 3 | 2021-07-01 | 030 | FTL | Y | 7 | 7.0 |
| 4 | 2021-07-01 | 060 | CompA | N | 11 | NaN |
| 5 | 2021-07-01 | 060 | CompB | N | 5 | NaN |
| 6 | 2021-07-01 | 060 | FTL | N | 28 | NaN |
| 7 | 2021-07-01 | 090 | CompA | N | 9 | NaN |
| 8 | 2021-07-01 | 090 | CompB | N | 15 | NaN |
| 9 | 2021-07-01 | 090 | FTL | N | 33 | NaN |

It looks like it is working but if I keep all the merged columns it is not matching everything up correctly.

line 1 clearly is not matching correctly engine_x and camp_x are n and n but engine_y and camp_y is n and y

|  | IS_MONTH_x | IS_DAYS_GROUP | VFMFRC | ENGINE_PROFILE_x | CAMPAIGN_PROFILE_x | UnitCount | IS_MONTH_y | ENGINE_PROFILE_y | CAMPAIGN_PROFILE_y | CompCodeCount | RPU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-07-01 | 030 | FTL | N | N | 44 | 2021-07-01 | N | Y | 7 | 6.285714 |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 030 | FTL | N | Y | 7 | 2021-07-01 | N | Y | 7 | 1.000000 |
| 2 | 2021-07-01 | 030 | FTL | Y | N | 8 | 2021-07-01 | N | Y | 7 | 1.142857 |
| 3 | 2021-07-01 | 090 | FTL | N | N | 29 | 2021-07-01 | N | Y | 4 | 7.250000 |
| 4 | 2021-07-01 | 090 | FTL | N | Y | 4 | 2021-07-01 | N | Y | 4 | 1.000000 |
| 5 | 2021-07-01 | 090 | FTL | Y | N | 7 | 2021-07-01 | N | Y | 4 | 1.750000 |
| 6 | 2021-07-01 | 120 | CompB | N | N | 15 | 2021-07-01 | N | Y | 3 | 5.000000 |
| 7 | 2021-07-01 | 120 | CompB | N | Y | 3 | 2021-07-01 | N | Y | 3 | 1.000000 |
| 8 | 2021-07-01 | 120 | CompB | Y | N | 1 | 2021-07-01 | N | Y | 3 | 0.333333 |
| 9 | 2021-07-01 | 120 | FTL | N | N | 30 | 2021-07-01 | N | Y | 2 | 15.000000 |

unit_count is 60 rows and camp_count is 24 rows. I suspect that has something to do with it but I am not able to figure out how to get these two to merge correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Units where `CAMPAIGN_PROFILE` is "N" don't have `CampCount`, therefore `NaN`. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Its not quite correct though. I added another example to show what is going on.